# Object does not exist after constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, dictionary, object, segmentation-fault

I have a constructor that looks like this (in c++):

```
Interpreter::Interpreter() {
        tempDat == new DataObject();
        tempDat->clear();
}
```

the constructor of dataObject does absolutely nothing, and clear does this:

```
bool DataObject::clear() {
        //clear the object

        if (current_max_id > 0) {
            indexTypeLookup.clear();
            intData.clear();
            doubleData.clear();
            current_max_id = 0;
        }

}
```

Those members are defined as follows:

```
std::map<int, int> indexTypeLookup;
std::map<int, int> intData;
std::map<int, double> doubleData;
```

Now the strange thing is that I'm getting a segfault on tempDat->clear(); gdb says tempDat is null. How is that possible? The constructor of tempDat cannot fail, it looks like this:

```
DataObject::DataObject() : current_max_id(0)
{

}
```

I know there are probably better way's of making such a data structure, but I really like to know where this segfault problem is coming from..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Interpreter::Interpreter() {
        tempDat == new DataObject(); // <- here
        tempDat->clear();
}
```

You're using `==` to assign. Use `=` instead:

```
        tempDat = new DataObject();
```

Using `==` gives you an expression that compares the current value of `tempDat` (some random garbage) to the address of the newly created `DataObject`. The result of that expression is immediately discarded, and `tempDat` remains unchanged. So it still contains random garbage, which happened to be `0` in your debugging session.

Comment: DOH! (how stupid is that....) Thanks, I did not see that after looking for an hour...